# Python: while KeyboardInterrupt is forwarded to multiprocessing child process?

Tags: python, windows, windows-8, 64-bit, multiprocessing

I have following test code executed on Windows:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def child() :
  while True :
    time.sleep( 2 )

if __name__ == '__main__' :
  multiprocessing.Process( target = child ).start()
  while True :
    time.sleep( 1 )
```

If i press `Ctrl-C` while it's working, i see **two** `KeyboardInterrupt` exceptions - one for `sleep( 1 )` and one for `sleep( 2 )`. How it's happens that keyboard interrupt in main `process` is forwarded to child `process`? They are processes after all, not threads :(.

Comment: These kind of things depend on the underlying OS, so you should also tag what OS you are running this on.

Comment: @Keith Added "windows" tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `KeyboardInterrupt` exception is thrown when a process [catches the `SIGINT` signal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) which indicates [a keyboard interrupt](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html)  (pressing ctrl+c).

In Unix/Linux systems the `SIGINT` signal is sent to the entire [foreground process group](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11_01_02) which includes the parent process and its child processes.

Comment: But i'm running this code on Windows. Is it same logic with Ctrl-C on windows even without `SIGTERM`?

Comment: Unsure. You should add the tag for your specific version of Windows... it might be relevant to the answer you get. Also, the signal is `SIGINT` (keyboard interrupt) _not_ `SIGTERM`.